# How should the model feedback to the view in android MVP?

Tags: android, android-mvp

I am using MVP to decouple my view and model in my android application. I need to know how the model should feedback the result of the business logic to the view.

If for example a button is pressed to login, the activity would be like this, using butterknife `@OnClick` annotation:

```
@OnClick(R.id.login_button)
public void login() {
    String email = mEmailEditText.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordEditText.getText().toString();
    LoginCredentials loginCredentials = new LoginCredentials(email, password);
    mPresenter.loginWithEmail(loginCredentials);
}
```

The presenter would then validate and make a request to the repository:

```
public void loginWithEmail(LoginCredentials loginCredentials) {
    boolean isEmailValid = AuthValidator.validateEmail(loginCredentials.getUsername());
    boolean isPasswordValid = AuthValidator.validatePassword(loginCredentials.getPassword());

    if(isEmailValid && isPasswordValid) repository.loginEmailUser(loginCredentials);

    if (!isEmailValid) view.handleInvalidEmail();

    if (!isPasswordValid) view.handleInvalidPassword();
}
```

The repository would then execute the business logic:

```
@Override
public void loginEmailUser(LoginCredentials loginCredentials) {
    Call<Token> call = userServiceApi.loginInToken(loginCredentials);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Token> call, @NonNull Response<Token> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                // handle successful login
            } else {
                // Handle unsuccessful login
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Token> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            // Handle failed request
        }
    });
```

Where the comments say `// handle unsuccessful something`, how does the model feedback to the view the outcomes of the business logic so that the view can handle these outcomes?

Thank you.

Comment: As usual ... with callback

Comment: Its done through the presenter with the view you attach to the presenter

Comment: If I knew what that was I wouldn't have asked the question. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a interface as callback, for example :

```
public interface RepositoryCallback {

   void onLoginEmailUserSuccess(/*paramaters if you need*/);
   void onLoginEmailUserError(/*paramaters if you need*/);
   void onRequestFailed(/*paramaters if you need*/)

}
```

In the repository defined the listener

```
public class MyRepository {

    private RepositoryCallback mListener;

    @Override
    public void loginEmailUser(LoginCredentials loginCredentials) {
        Call<Token> call = userServiceApi.loginInToken(loginCredentials);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Token> call, @NonNull Response<Token> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // handle successful login
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onLoginEmailUserSuccess()
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle unsuccessful login
                   if (mListener != null) {
                       mListener.onLoginEmailUserError()
                   }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Token> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                // Handle failed request
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onRequestFailed()
                }
            }
        });

    public void setRepositoryCallback(RepositoryCallback listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

}
```

Then set the presenter as listener :

```
public class MyPresenter implements RepositoryCallback {


    public void loginWithEmail(LoginCredentials loginCredentials) {
        repository.setRepositoryCallback(this) // here or in the presenter constructor
        boolean isEmailValid = AuthValidator.validateEmail(loginCredentials.getUsername());
        boolean isPasswordValid = AuthValidator.validatePassword(loginCredentials.getPassword());

        if(isEmailValid && isPasswordValid) repository.loginEmailUser(loginCredentials);

        if (!isEmailValid) view.handleInvalidEmail();

        if (!isPasswordValid) view.handleInvalidPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginEmailUserSuccess(//paramaters if you need){
        // your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginEmailUserError(//paramaters if you need){
        // your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailed(//paramaters if you need){
        // your code
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Is there an alternative? @Cochi

Comment: This is the casual and the simplest implementation for your issue. However you can use the [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)  or [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) libraries as alternative.
EventBus is very simple to use , RxJava is powerful and maybe to big for your use case.